# How to unsubscribe from firebase realtime listener if listener is redux action?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-native-firebase

I am trying to figure out best way to combiner firebase and redux.
I have collection which I need to listen changes to.
This is redux action that subscribe to that collection and on result dispatch data to reducer.

```
export const configListener = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('config')
      .doc(id)
      .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        dispatch(configFetched(documentSnapshot.data()));
      });
}
```

It's fine, but, I can't figure out how to unsubscribe from this listener now.
I had idea to store subscribers in reducer but this just seems wrong.
Any help :)

configListener action is called when screen opens but I need to unsubscribe once screen is dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can actually return values from an action. You can grab it from the dispatch call and use it in your component

```
const Screen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = dispatch(configListener(id)) // id comes from somewhere
    return () => {
      //clean up
      subscriber();
    };
  }, [id])
  
  return <SomeUI />;
}
```

And add the return in your thunk (I'm assuming you're using redux-thunk)

```
export const configListener = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('config')
      .doc(id)
      .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        dispatch(configFetched(documentSnapshot.data()));
      });
  return subscriber;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that solution but didn’t know it’s good practice to return something from actions.